# How to use lifetimes in py_class! in rust-cpython?

Tags: python, rust

I use [rust-cpython](https://github.com/dgrunwald/rust-cpython) and Rust for a Python .so lib. I wanted to create a class like this:

```
py_class!(class MyType |py| {
    data s: Into<Cow<'a, str>>;

    ....
}
```

But it doesn't allow to use a lifetime:

```
error[E0261]: use of undeclared lifetime name `'p`
   |
81 |     data s: Into<Cow<'a, str>>;
   |                      ^^ undeclared lifetime
```

And it doesn't allow to write:

```
py_class!(class MyType<'a> |py| {
```

with error:

```
error: no rules expected the token `<`
   |
79 | py_class!(class MyType<'a> |py| {
   |                        ^
```

Maybe I'm not so good in Rust, maybe `rust-cpython` doesn't allow it. What is the problem and how would I use lifetimes in macros in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://dgrunwald.github.io/rust-cpython/doc/cpython/macro.py_class.html):

> Because Python code can pass all Python objects to other threads, `data_type` must be `Send + 'static`.

Since everything inside the type must be `'static`, there would be no point to allowing a lifetime parameter on the class.